# How to I change the blogger's name button from all lower case to proper case in Omega 3.1 subtheme?

Tags: theming

I want **firstname lastname's blog** to be **Firstname Lastname's blog**

Answer (score 1):

You could always use [mb-convert-case](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php), or you could just target it with css and use text-transform: capitalize.

Comment: I would like to target it with css and use text-transform: capitalize but I don't know where to find the class or ID.

Comment: Do you mean you can't find it in the CSS file, or you just can't figure out what the name of the class is?

Comment: I think I know where to put the CSS but I don't know the name of the class.

Comment: You could always use google Chrome's inspector to find out what that element is wrapped in. To do that, open the page you want to work on in chrome, right click on the element, and select "Inspect element." That will give you the html in a nice drill down code view and you should be able to find it that way.